# awakeFromNib method is getting called twice UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, xib

I am using XIB to create a UITableviewCell in my view controller. I registered the cell class to table view as follows:

> self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ThisWeekCell", bundle: nil),
>   forCellReuseIdentifier: "ThisWeekCellIdentifier")

In cellForRowAt Indexpath method I am dequeuing the cell as follows:

> tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
>   "ThisWeekCellIdentifier") as! ThisWeekCell

When I am dequeuing the cell, the cell's awakeFromNib method is getting called twice. In the first call all the outlet properties are set but in the second call all are nil.

The problem that I am facing is: None of the constraints that I set in xib file are getting reflected when I am displaying the cell.[image: Constraints for Cell]
[image]

Comment: Do you see any difference if you change your dequeue line to: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ThisWeekCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ThisWeekCell` ?

Comment: No still the same issue

Comment: OK - what else are you doing in code? I just looked back at a sample I did, and I definitely do *not* get a double call to `awakeFromNib` and the constraints work fine.

Comment: Can you share the sample as I am not doing anything extra.

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/DonMag/SWSimpleDynamicCells

Comment: FYI, it's usually helpful if you post whole methods rather than just single lines. Often the problem isn't where you think it is.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm facing the same problem